# Initialize private readonly fields after Deserializing

Tags: c#, initialization, private, deserialization, readonly

I need to initialize private readonly field after Deserialization. I have folowing DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        // Constructor not called at Deserialization 
        // because of FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject is used
        // so field will not be initialized by constructor at Deserialization
        _privateReadonlyField = new object();
    }

    // Initialization will not be called at Deserialization (same reason as for constructor)
    private readonly object _privateReadonlyField = new object();

    [DataMember]
    public string SomeSerializableProperty { get; set; }

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // With this line code even not compiles, since readonly fields can be initialized only in constructor
        _privateReadonlyField = new object();
    }
}
```

All what I need, that after Deserialization _privateReadonlyField is not null.

Any suggestions about this - is it possible at all? 
Or I need to remove "readonly" key, which is not a good option.

Comment: What serialization method are you using? The construction of the objects differ for different methods.

Comment: What's wrong with marking your `_privateReadonlyField` a `[DataMember]`? Data contract serializer would take care of it without a problem.

Comment: Joachim Isaksson:I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer but actually this does not matter - all Serializers use FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject when Deserializing.

Comment: dasblinkenlight: I don't need to serialize value of the field. I just need to get this field is not null when my Item is deserialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any field declared as `private readonly` can be instantiated in the same line where it was declared or inside a constructor. Once that is done it cannot be changed.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=VS.71).aspx):

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

That means that you will have to remove `readonly` keyword to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, Huske. Unfortunately you approved my feeling about this, I hoped that some way exists to solve this problem.

Answer (score 10):

Serialization is able to read in values for read-only fields because it uses reflection, which ignores accessibility rules.  It can be argued that the following is, therefore, justified as part of the serialization process, even though I would recommend strongly against it in almost any other circumstance:

```
private readonly Doodad _oldField;

[OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
private readonly Widget _newField;

[OnDeserialized]
private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    if (_oldField != null && _newField == null)
    {
        var field = GetType().GetField("_newField",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        field.SetValue(this, new Widget(_oldField));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I really forgot about reflection, when asked the question.

Comment: What effect does the `[OptionalField]` attribute have on this solution? Does `OnDeserialized` still work without it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, omitting it will cause deserialization to throw an exception when reading input that doesn't contain that field.

Comment: This works well for setting readonly fields on deserialized reference objects, but does not work at all for setting readonly fields on deserialized value objects, which is where I needed it. Still a good answer.

Comment: Well, turns out this _does_ work, but you have to box `this` before calling `SetValue`, and then unbox it _by assiging to `this`_. I had no idea you could assign to `this` for structs. I knew you couldn't do it for classes. I have learned much this evening. Here's a gist showing the box/unbox: https://gist.github.com/rummelsworth/938180ba2ef4d74d9b8d86dcba295bd6