# Object obtained from WCF service has null private fields, even though they are initialized in the class

Tags: wcf, null, field, private, datacontract

I'm obtaining an object from a WCF service. One of the fields in the object is a private field of type `NodaTime.IClock`, called `timeProvider`, the field is essentially used for dependency injection (via a constructor overload) to supply a fake clock during testing.

However, instances I obtain from the WCF service have this field set to null, even though the class explicitly initializes the field in both the field declaration and in the default constructor (which is private).

I don't think it makes sense for the field to be part of the data contract, but I don't want it *ever* to be null. I can't figure out how it is getting get set to null, there is no path in the code that allows that.

How do I ensure that this field has a value when obtained from WCF?

**[Update]**
I found this in the WCF documentation:

> During deserialization, an uninitialized object is first created, without calling any constructors on the type. Then all data members are deserialized

This does explain why my constructors have no effect, but I'm surprised that it defeats even a field initializer. I may need to make this field part of the data contract after all, or find a way to initialize it after it is deserialized.

**[Update 2]**
I found this very similar question [Initialize private readonly fields after Deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328720/initialize-private-readonly-fields-after-deserializing) I have therefore flagged my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: You should probably not be passing around such complicated objects through WCF. It works out much better if the objects being sent and received are more DTO (Data Transfer Objects) - just data. No methods, or anything else.

Comment: In the end, I went with the solution proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12398681/98516